# PHP JSON ERROR json_decode() file_get_contents($url

Tags: php, json, instagram-api

i am getting this error

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in 
>  Warning: Invalid
>   argument supplied for foreach()

```
$username = strtolower($username); // sanitization
$token = $token;
$url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=".$username."&access_token=".$token;
echo $url;
$get = @file_get_contents($url, 0);
var_dump($get);
$json = json_decode($get);
//var_dump($json = json_decode($get));

foreach($json->data as $user)
{
    if($user->username == $username)
    {
        return $user->id;
    }
}
```

Comment: you already have the `var_dump`. investigate

Comment: Suppressing possible errors/warnings while trying to find out why a script doesn’t work is not clever … remove the `@`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, you are not authenticating (https://instagram.com/developer/authentication/#) therefore your `$json = false` andsince you are trying a property from false. Thatis why you are getting that error